# Finding the number of enabled checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This gets the number of checkboxes:

```
var numCheckboxes = $('input').filter(':checkbox').length;
```

But how do I filter for `.prop('disabled',false)`?

Answer (score 6):

```
$("input:checkbox:enabled").length
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bYygJ/

Notes:

- Uses [`input:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) to find all input elements of type `checkbox`, combined with
- [`enabled`](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) pseudo-class selector

Comment: I love a neatly written selector!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').filter(':checkbox:not(:disabled)').length
```